# How to get list of publications via Anguilla framework?

Tags: 2011, cme

In the Tridion GUI, I have to show a list of the current publications through the Tridion JavaScript Anguilla framework.

Unfortunately, I didn't find any methods which return the publications for the logged in user.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
var root = $models.getItem($const.TCMROOT);
var list = root.getListPublications();

function onListLoaded() {
    $evt.removeEventHandler(list, "load", onListLoaded);
    list.getXml(); // Here the Publications XML for the current logged user.
}

$evt.addEventHandler(list, "load", onListLoaded);

list.load(true);
```

Comment: Eric became @puf?

Comment: Mr. P is in our hearts and amygdalas.